# How to install Yiistrap? I got CException Property "CUrlManager.bootstrap" is not defined

Tags: php, css, yii, installation, cexception

I just have installed the yii framework and then I tried to install yiistrap on it. I followed the guide on:
http://www.getyiistrap.com/site/started
and
http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/60019-how-to-install-yiistrap-using-composer/

but it comes to the same error:
CException
Property "CUrlManager.bootstrap" is not defined.

I use yii-bootstrap-0.9.12.r211 as suggested on a member post: [Twitter Bootstrap in Yii](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11866179/twitter-bootstrap-in-yii), but it still didn't work.

I did 3 modifications:

Inside extentions/bootstrap/components/Bootstrap.php

```
public function init() {
    $this->registerAllCss();
    $this->registerJs();
    parent::init();
}
```

Inside config/main.php

```
<?php

// uncomment the following to define a path alias
// Yii::setPathOfAlias('local','path/to/local-folder');

// This is the main Web application configuration. Any writable
// CWebApplication properties can be configured here.

Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
    ...

    'theme'=>'bootstrap',
    'modules'=>array(
        'gii'=>array(
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),                      
        ),
    ),

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'=>array('log'),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'=>array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'bootstrap.helpers.TbHtml',
    ),

    'modules'=>array(
        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool
        'gii'=>array(
            ...
          ),
    ),

    // application components
    'components'=>array(

        'user'=>array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
        ),

        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),

        'bootstrap'=>array(
        'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
            ),

        ),

                // database settings are configured in database.php
        'db'=>require(dirname(__FILE__).'/database.php'),

        'errorHandler'=>array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction'=>'site/error',
        ),

        'log'=>array(
            'class'=>'CLogRouter',
            'routes'=>array(
                array(
                    'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels'=>'error, warning',
                ),
                // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
                /*
                array(
                    'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
                ),
                */
            ),
        ),

    ),

    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params'=>array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail'=>'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Inside views/layouts/main.php, in  the middle of `<head> ... </head>`

```
<?php Yii::app()->bootstrap->register(); ?>
```

Please help me to save my time. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `'bootstrap'` inside url-manager array. This is incorrect. You should do this:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ),

'bootstrap'=>array(
    'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
 ),
```

Comment: Thanks @hamed, the first barrier is gone, but it comes to the second. I got new CException: </br></br>

Alias "bootstrap.components.TbApi" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. </br>
As suggested on stackoverflow.com/questions/21641401/…, I added 

</br></br>
    'import'=>array( ... 
'bootstrap.helpers.*', 
'bootstrap.widgets.*', 
'bootstrap.behaviors.*', ), 

</br></br>
into config/main.php, but it didnt work. Any idea? Tx before –

Comment: Thanks @hamed, the first barrier is gone, but it comes to the second. I got new CException: 
<br>
`Alias "bootstrap.components.TbApi" is invalid. Make sure it points to an existing PHP file and the file is readable. `

How can I resolve this?